# xamarin - Communicate with Xamarin/Mono DLL from native app

Tags: xamarin

Is it possible to communicate with a Xamarin/Mono DLL/assembly from a native app (e.g. for iOS - from Swift code, for Android - from Java code)?
If yes, how can I do that?

I remember that in the first versions of MonoTouch both Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop and Xcode were used (especially for UI/xib binding).
Is this possibility still available? Of course, not for UI but for simple API calls - like interop but the other way around (i.e. Swift/Obj-C -> C# not C# -> Swift/Obj-C).

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe if you look to the open sourced xamarin you can do something, but strictly speaking no, there's no way for what you want, at least not out of the box. Xamarin still uses xcode for compilation as it's compiled to native code, but that doesn't means you can get a .net dll and use it directly from native code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way atm is documented here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/